# Testing a fibonacci heap - what cases to consider?

Tags: heap

i am currently testing a extractMinimum() method of a fibonacci heap implementation i did for a programming exercise.

The way, the method is supposed to work:

```
1. Delete the minimum node    
2. Find a new minimum in the remaining root list elements    
3. Add the children of the old minimum node, left of the new 
   minimum
```

And, i did already consider the following test cases:

```
1. empty-Heap  
2. one heap with only one root-element and no children  
3. one heap with only one root-element and one child  
4. one heap with many root elements and one child  
5. one heap with many root elements and multiple children
```

In all of these tests, i also check if the ranks are correctly computed and I also check if rootlist elements are all unmarked. And the references are set correctly.

So, my question is: Did I miss a certain edge case, is there something else i should consider while testing?

Comment: You should do some random testing: shuffle a list of the numbers 0 to 1000, and feed them to an empty heap. Call extractMin repeatedly and check that the numbers come out in sorted order. Repeat the test 1000 times (each time with a different shuffling).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should do exhaustive testing of your implementation taking into consideration these 5 criteria: Correctness, Mutation, Coverage, Feasibility, and Randomness. You can follow the following article for reference: https://users.ece.utexas.edu/~khurshid/papers/MarinovETAL03Evaluation.pdf